# Xamarin iOS: Deploying app to device or simulator with iOS 15

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios15

I would like to verify whether my Xamarin iOS app is ready for iOS 15 before it's official release. I've installed the public beta of iOS 15 on my iPad and there seems to be an issue, so I would like to debug it. Unfortunately I'm neither able to deploy the app to my device nor can I deploy it do an iOS 15 simulator, because they are not appearing in the dropdown.

I did the following things:

- updated MacOS to the newest version (11.5.1)
- updated Visual Studio for Mac to the newest version (8.10.6)
- updated Xcode to the newest version (12.5.1)

Since this didn't work I've installed the Xcode-beta (version 13.0 beta 4) and changed the SDK location in Visual Studio to Xcode-beta.app.

Unfortunately there are still no simulators appearing in the dropdown and when I try to deploy the app to my device I'm getting the following error:

```
error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'IBFoundation' (path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/IBFoundation): not found.
```

Am I missing something? Is it even possible to be able to debug Xamarin.iOS apps with iOS 15 or is Visual Studio just not ready yet?

**UPDATE:**

I've changed my SDK location in Visual Studio back to the stable Xcode version, unloaded and reloaded the project and now I'm able to deploy to my iPad. So I'm not sure whether the stuff I did before actually changed something or Visual Studio just had another unrelated problem previously..

Would still be good to know how you could get the simulators to work as well.

Comment: have you switched VS to the preview channel?

Comment: yup, it also says "Up to date"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, installed xcode 15 beta 4 and wired it up to the latest VS Mac preview and it wouldn't let me deploy/debug to the ios 15 device - "error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'IBFoundation' (path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/IBFoundation): not found." and no simulators either. What I could do (and I'm sure this makes me a bad person) is drop back to xcode 12.5 and copy over the supporting ios 15 platform files to that package, restore the latest "stable" Xamarin and run using the SDK xcode 12.5 location. Basically I copied the "15.0" folder from beta to the current latest xcode. Aka copy /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.0 to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport It lets me deploy and debug on an ios 15 device from VS Mac and also access the simulators and that is what I'm after. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgEyy.png)

Comment: I've copied the folder like you mentioned above but I still can't see any iOS 15 simulators in the dropdown. Did you do something else for the simulators?

Comment: Nope, I don't have them either, despite copying this directory

Comment: Unable to reproduce this by copying ios15 folder. Still not getting ios15 simulators in my VS Mac

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, I can deploy(by start debugging) on my iOS device with iOS 15 Beta 4, launch the app manually and debug it after that.

My development machine has not changed (no preview vs4mac nor Xcode/macOS beta)

Comment: So you're saying it's possible to debug on a physical device with the beta? Have the simulators worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get iOS15 working on the simulator from Visual Studio.

1. Install Xcode-beta from developer.apple.com/downloads
2. Once installed, close out of all simulators
3. Open Xcode-beta, go to Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator, that should open an iOS15 simulator
4. Close out of visual studio
5. Wait until the simulator is fully up and running, then open Visual Studio and the simulator should show up in the list as shown below

[image]

Comment: The simulator shows up in the list indeed, but when I'm trying to run the app on it Visual Studio gets stuck at "Waiting for the debugger to connect to the iOS Simulator...". I've also noticed when doing this the simulator without the beta badge opens up and closes immediately.

Comment: @tobi_b Were you able to get it to work? I have the same issue "waiting for debugger..."

Comment: nope, unfortunately not, I've used my real device for testing.

Comment: When I got stuck in that state I just restarted the phone in the sim and the app came up with the phone. Device > Restart.